# Angular ag-grid - how do I collect a header clicked event?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I want to catch an event from a header click in a non-sorted column and I can't figure out how to do so.  I can get it if I turn on sorting with `onSortChanged` but if I do that, I can't suppress the sort/turn off the arrows form displaying.  Any ideas how to simply grab the a header clicked event?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using addEventListener on Header cell

```
 this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
          enableSorting: false,
          enableFilter: true,
          onGridReady: (params) =>{
            const header = document.querySelectorAll('.ag-header-cell');
        console.log(header);
        header.forEach(v => {
          v.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            console.log("clicked")
          })
        });
          }
        };
```

working code for reference- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-54vy3p?file=app/my-grid-application/my-grid-application.component.ts

Currently there is only rowClick events and no Column header events