# sort multiple columns on Column header click in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In documentation,  sorting api i.e columns API method "**applyColumnState**" used for sorting multiple columns on external button click

But Can we sort multiple columns on a Column header click?

For eg, On Column A header cell click I want Column A to be sorted desencding and Column B to be sort ascending.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

from the docs : https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/row-sorting/#sorting-api

you can manually sort through multiple columns, one after one using the ColumnState API:

```
gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: [
      { colId: 'country', sort: 'asc', sortIndex: 0 },
      { colId: 'sport', sort: 'asc', sortIndex: 1 },
    ],
    defaultState: { sort: null },
  });
```

if you want to click on a header and sort an other one, you can disable sorting on the header in question, listen for the click on it an execute the above `applyColumnState` to manually sort.

you can listen to the click on the header by adding a listener on the `.ag-header-cell` class (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812319/6641693) or simply by creating your own header component that would trigger any function you want using `headerComponentFramework` on the column Definition :

```
headerComponentFramework: (params) =>{
 return (
  <div>
   .....
  </div>
 )
}
```